# 25 GB available not shown in UbuntuOne home folder

Tags: ubuntu-one

I bought 20+ GB of extra storage on Ubuntu-one. Ubuntu-One CP on my laptop correctly shows the storage available, but then the UbuntuOne folder on my home shows only 3,6Gb available, this creates an error if I try to upload my 10Gbs of data through the Ubuntu-One folder. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 4):

This means that there is 3.6 GB available locally, on the partition where a copy of your cloud-stored files is stored. So to actually use these 20 GB of space you have on the cloud, you need 20 GB of free space on the partition where Ubuntu One keeps your local copy of your cloud-stored files.